# Is this proof of $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^k \leq (\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i)^k$ correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I came across the following proof, and although I believe the result, something seems fishy and I can't put my finger on it.  The base case might not be enough, or we might have to consider various $k$ somewhere...or maybe I'm just paranoid !  So, does that make sense ?

Given a sequence $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ of positive integers, we show 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^k \leq (\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i)^k$$
for any positive integers $n$ and $k$, by induction on $n$.

If $n = 1$, then obviously $a_1^k \leq a_1^k$.  So assume truth for values smaller than $n$.  Then

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^k = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} a_i^k + a_n^k \\
\leq (\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} a_i)^k + a_n^k$$

by induction.  Now, setting $x = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} a_i$ we get

$$(\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} a_i)^k + a_n^k = x^k + a_n^k \leq (x + a_n)^k$$

again by induction, and replacing $x$ by its values lets us conclude that

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^k \leq (x + a_n)^k = (\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i)^k$$

Comment: The case $n=2$ seems to be missing. But it is easy. (But then it all is, imagine expanding.)

Comment: Ah indeed the base case should be $n = 2$.  That's what was missing.  I was aware that this proof was overkill, but I had to determine if it was right or not.  So if nothing else is missing, the case is closed.  Thank you for your answer (you can post this as an answer if you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a gap, which is of the same kind as the "all horses are of the same colour" induction "proof." The case $n=2$ was not done, and it is essential for the induction step.

The case $n=2$ can be done using the Binomial Theorem. It can also be done by induction on $k$.

Comment: I don't get it. Why is a base case $n = 2$ necessary? The proof seems complete to me.

Comment: @user143882:  First, let us note that the result is clear (Binomial Theorem), so the only issue is a technical one about proof by induction. The point is that  the case $n=2$ has not been proved, since the next to last displayed line uses the case $n=2$. One way to view things is that if $k=4$, the case $n=1$ is true even if some of the $a_i$ are negative, while the case $n=2$ is not.

Comment: I think get it now. I was assuming $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 ≤ (a + b) ^ 2$ had already been proved. You're viewing addition as a special case of sum. I was viewing addition as being defined before sum, and then sum being defined in terms of addition. In my view $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 ≤ (a + b) ^ 2$ could have been proved before we got to the facts about sum. Maybe my view is the view the OP came across.

Comment: @user143882: Your last comment I think identifies the source of the problem. You are thinking that the induction is being done on the *exponents*. Actually, in the proof the exponent $k$ is fixed, and induction is being done on the number of terms.

Comment: No, I'm aware the proof is by induction on $n$. In the previous comment I meant to write $a ^ n + b ^ n ≤ (a + b) ^ n$, but made a mistake and wrote $2$ instead of $n$.

$$ ∑ _ {i = 1} ^ n a _ i ^ k = ∑ _ {i = 1} ^ {n - 1} a _ i ^ k + a _ n ^ k ≤ \left( ∑ _ {i = 1} ^ {n - 1} a _ i \right) ^ k + a _ n ^ k ≤ \left( ∑ _ {i = 1} ^ {n - 1} a _ i + a _ n \right) ^ k = \left( ∑ _ {i = 1} ^ {n} a _ i \right) ^ k $$

Answer (score 2):

Alternately let $x_i = \dfrac{a_i}{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_j}$, then $0 < x_i < 1$, and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$. Thus we have:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k \leq \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$ since $0 < x_i^k \leq x_i < 1$ for $\forall k \geq 1$