# An inequality for series with fractional exponent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, fractions

Let $\{a_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a bounded and non negative sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, suppose that there exists $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that: $a_k=0$, $\forall k\geq N$. Let $p\in(0,1)$. Is true that:
$$\biggl( \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_k\biggr)^p\leq\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_k^p \; ?$$
The series above are convergent.
I have tried to use the fact that the function $x^p$, $x\geq 0$, is concave, but this give me:
$(x+y)^p\geq 2^{1-p}(x^p+y^p)$, $x\geq0$,bat it is useless.
I think that i have to use something inequality for finite sum as above and then pass to the limit.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1328704/42969

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/819478/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2698148/42969

Comment: Generally, concave + non-negative functions are *subadditive.*

Comment: Ok for sums over positive integers, but how i can extend the result for sums over all integers? Continuity is enough?

Comment: Yes, as demonstrated in the answer in the first link.

Comment: @inoc I think Karamata helps here immediately.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2698267/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows fom the fact that $$(x+y)^p \leq x^p +y^p $$ which cam be as belov $$(x+y)^p =\frac{x+y}{(x+y)^{1-p} } =\frac{x}{(x+y)^{1-p} } +\frac{y}{(x+y)^{1-p} } \leq \frac{x}{(x)^{1-p} } +\frac{y}{(y)^{1-p} } =x^p +y^p$$ and then by induction $$\left(\sum_{k=l}^n x_k\right)^p \leq \sum_{k=l}^n x_k^p $$
for any finite summation.
The infinite case is a consequence of finite summation case.